# Is it possible to change style for selected (or active) state of RaisedButton for material-ui version 0.18?

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, material-ui

I have this button from material-ui v0.18, and I need to change color and border when selected. In newer versions there are classes property but this one doesn't let me change it neither through css as it doesn't understand active or hover as it should.

Comment: As from the [documentation], it accepts both `className` and `style` props. let's say that active means "Already Clicked"?.

Comment: Yes, clicked.. in newer version of material-ui I found out that button has property selected, but 0.18 doesn't.